# Python: How do I get an IF statement to recognize a keyword from user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Just began coding a few weeks ago so forgive my ignorance.

I want to make it so that my IF statement will recognize a keyword from the user input rather then it having to be an exact match.

So instead of the user having to type exactly "Light" they could type something like "Go to the light" and the IF statement will still recognize "Light" as the keyword and proceed through that IF or ELIF statement.

```
def start_room():
    if not power:
        print("You are in pitch darkness, the only thing you can see is a faint green glow from beneath the silhouette of a door to your left.")
        print("What will you do?")
        choice = input("> ")

        if choice == "Light":
            print("yadayadayada")
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will work

```
def start_room():
    if not power:
        print("You are in pitch darkness, the only thing you can see is a faint green glow from beneath the silhouette of a door to your left.")
        print("What will you do?")
        choice = input("> ")

    if any([True for i in ['light', 'left'] if i in choice.lower()]):
        print("yadayadayada")
```

Comment: thank you, does the .lower refer to the answer being in lowercase letters?

Comment: just making 'light' work with both capital and normal case

Comment: you can just do `any([True for i in ['light', 'bulb', 'on'] if i in choice.lower()])`

Comment: I'm struggling with this, could you please show me what it would look like in the context of my code if i wanted 'light' and 'left' to be the two keywords. It didnt work when i copied it with my keywords.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: Oh I see, i was missing the IF before any, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing like this:

```
if "Light" in choice:
    print("yadayadayada")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `in` keyword. Try `if "light" in choice:`

Comment: What if i wanted multiple keywords but only need one of them to proceed?